# The property $m \otimes_A n = 0$ for modules over an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, projective-module

For $A$ a not necessarily commutative algebra over a field $\mathbb{k}$, can there exist two bi-modules $M$ and $N$ over $A$ such that, for some $m \in M$, and $n \in N$,
$$
m \otimes_A n = 0?
$$

I can see that this cannot happen if $N$ is projective as a left $A$-module, which is the case I happen to work with. However I am 
curious to know if projectivity is necessary to prevent $m \otimes_A n = 0$. I know that such examples exist over general rings, but for the special case of algebras over a field it is not clear to me what happens.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Is the condition that that $M$ and $N$ need to fulfill that $m \otimes_A n = 0$ **for every** $m \in M$ and $n \in N$?

Comment: Also, please provide some context. What are your thoughts on the problem? Could you tell us how or where you encountered it?

Comment: I have edited to make the question clearer, and added some comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can certainly happen. For example if $A = \Bbbk[X]$ and $M = N = A/(X^2)$, then $X \otimes X$ is an element of $M \otimes_A N$ which vanishes (because $X \otimes X = 1 \cdot X \otimes X = 1 \otimes X^2 = 0$).

Comment: Will all examples of $N$ be finite dimensional? Can you produce an infinite-dimensional example?

Comment: Take an infinite direct sum of copies of $\Bbbk[X]/(X^2)$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks! A last question - is it correct to now conclude from this that $A/(X^2)$, or an infinite direct sum of copies, is not projective as an $A$-module?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A projective module is flat, here you can a counterexample to flatness.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the exact sequence?

Comment: Let $I$ be the image of $(X)$ under the quotient map $\Bbbk[X] \to \Bbbk[X]/(X^2)$. Then $I \to M$ is injective but $I \otimes_A N \to M \otimes_A N$ is not.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!